# Calculate value based on value from same column of the previous row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I have an issue where I have to calculate a column using a formula that uses the value from the calculation done in the previous row.

I have tried the lag function but cannot get past the 2nd row.  After that all my values are null, since that column originally starts as null.  I feel like I am missing something.

I need to calculate a new column, using the formula:

```
MovingRate = MonthlyRate + (0.7 * MovingRatePrevious)
```

... where the `MovingRatePrevious` is the `MovingRate` of the prior row.  For month 1, I have the value so I do not need to re-calculate that but I need that value to be able to calculate the subsequent rows.  I need to partition by Type.

This is my original dataset:

```
Month   Type    MonthyRate  MovingRate
--------------------------------------
1       Blue    0.400       0.330
2       Blue    0.300   
3       Blue    0.700   
4       Blue    0.900
```

Desired results in `MovingRate` column:

```
Month   Type    MonthyRate  MovingRate
---------------------------------------
1       Blue    0.400       0.330
2       Blue    0.300       0.531
3       Blue    0.700       1.072
4       Blue    0.900       1.650
```

Comment: Please post the SQL that you tried

Comment: Where does 0.330 come from?

Comment: It is a hard-coded calculation since there is no previous value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate it using recursive CTE. Below is a generalized version for your data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Month INT, Type VARCHAR(100), MonthlyRate DECIMAL(18, 3));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'Blue', 0.400),
(2, 'Blue', 0.300),
(3, 'Blue', 0.700),
(4, 'Blue', 0.900);

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Month) AS rn
    FROM @t
), rcte AS (
    SELECT *, CAST(0.330 AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) AS MovingRate
    FROM cte1 AS base
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT curr.*, CAST(curr.MonthlyRate + 0.7 * prev.MovingRate AS DECIMAL(18, 3))
    FROM cte1 AS curr
    JOIN rcte AS prev ON curr.Type = prev.type AND curr.rn = prev.rn + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM rcte
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for!  I have never used recursive CTE so thank you for showing me how.  Again, thank you - I had spent so many hours trying to figure it out.