# Calculate with previous value calculated in sql databricks

Tags: sql, window, databricks, lag, partition-by

Please, I need help to build a query that calculate the value using the previous value calculated at the same column.

It would be something like that:

```
Select ID
,n
,CASE WHEN n=1 THEN col1 ELSE col1+col3 END AS col2
,LAG(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY n) AS col3
from table
```

Databricks returns:

> The feature is not supported: Referencing a lateral column alias
> `col2` in window expression "LAG(lateralAliasReference(col2)) OVER
> (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY n ASC NULLS FIRST unspecifiedframe$())".

I tried:
table2 AS (SELECT *
,col1  AS col2
FROM table
WHERE n=1
UNION ALL
SELECT curr.*, curr.col1+prev.col2 AS col2
FROM table AS curr
INNER JOIN table2 AS prev
ON curr.Id = prev.Id AND curr.n= prev.n+ 1
)

SELECT *
FROM table2

It says that on "INNER JOIN table2 AS prev" , table2 cannot be found.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected outputs ?

Comment: Do you have a column called "col3" in your data? Databricks actually does support lateral aliases (as of 12.2 and later), but if you are aliasing your expression with an existing column name it might not know how to resolve because it looks circular.

Comment: I do wrote the column col3. It doesnt work at all. I tried the following solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563428/calculate-value-based-on-value-from-same-column-of-the-previous-row and it says  that table rcte can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Create col2 in a *derived table* to have it available.

```
select ID, n, col2
      ,LAG(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY n) AS col3
from (
  Select ID
        ,n
        ,CASE WHEN n=1 THEN col1 ELSE col1+col3 END AS col2
  from table
) dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` clause within a window function :

```
SELECT ID, n,
      LAG(CASE WHEN n=1 THEN col1 ELSE col1+col3 END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY n) AS col3
FROM mytable;
```